# Endless if-else loop statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

it took my 2 days and I am still unable to find the way to get rid off this endless loop. I have toggle in my html template and using bootstrap switch toggle. I am sending data to my php and based on the response I am making toggle on or off. Therefore I have `if()` `else{}` statement but it goes in both if as well as else part and it never ends. toggle switches on and of endlessly. Please see the code below:

```
function onToggle() {

    var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
    $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
        let id = $(element).val();
        let sid = $(element).val();
        let isChecked = $("#sce_"+sid).is(':checked');
        $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

            if(this.checked ) {
                updateStatus(1, id, page, sid, $(this));
            }
                else{
                updateStatus(0, id, page, sid, $(this));
                }

        });
    });
}

function updateStatus(status_val, id, page, sid, cbRef) {
id = 9;

    let isChecked = $("#sce_"+sid).is(':checked');
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/" + page,
        data: {
            status: status_val,
            id: id
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if (result[0] == "Success!") {
                if (status_val == 1) {
                    $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                } else if (status_val == 0) {
                    $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                }
            } else {

                if (status_val == 1) {
                    $("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('off');
                    cbRef.prop('checked', false);
                }   else  { 
                    $("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('on');
                    cbRef.prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
}
```

As you see I am trying to switch toggle off and on in especially this part:

```
  if (status_val == 1) {
                        $("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('off');
                        cbRef.prop('checked', false);
                    }   else  { 
                        $("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('on');
                        cbRef.prop('checked', true);
                    }
```

But it turns off and on once I press any toggle. Because it goes to `if()` part then `else{}` part no matter what condition there is. Tried to add temporary variable but couldn't figure out. Tried to use .`die()` but did not help. Tried to use `return` in each if as well as else part, thought maybe it might help, but did not help. 48 hours and I am in the same place, was not able to find solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the html part below :

```
 <form method="post" id="toggleForm_{{$detail['id']}}">
            <input  type="checkbox" id="id_{{$detail['id']}}" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" name="sce" id="sce_{{$detail['id']}}" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $detail['status'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            <input type="hidden" class="statusForDetail" value="{{$detail['id']}}" page="sections-set-status" >
        </form>
```

The front end is looking like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't know JQuery, but I understand javascript. I see you are trying to do some manipulation inside of an async block, can you some how get that work outside of that ajax block, and use a callback to do the work once the request has return?  

It may not even be the problem, but I am curious if that is somehow interfering with what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes you are right, I am doing some checking inside of the async block. You think this will prevent script goes to if as well as else statement? Because what I need is to break everything and stop all once it goes to if. But in this case it reads both if and else in any case. I will try to put it outside of async part.

Comment: I am not totally sure, but one thing I would try is to just let the request complete and return, then find out what the status is, then do your work.   

Also I have found that check boxes have given me problems in the past, managing that check attribute in other frameworks is a real thorn in the side sometimes, but for JQuery I am not sure.

Comment: The same nightmare is happening to me right now. you mean I should call function for example in the else part or even after success part? Because tried that but did not help..

Comment: Listen, a note of encouragement: embrace these annoying programming issues, they are our best teachers, this issue will be seared into your memory and you'll never forget how difficult it was, and through perseverance you will find the solution.

But on the practical side of helping, what calls the onToggle function?

Comment: Thanks for this encouragement. The `onToggle` function checks the change in toggle switch if it's state has been changed then it sends the new state information to the `updateStatus()` function where we do the rest.  This is so ridiculous that even I attain new variable it still goes to the else part even in the outside of async part. Completely confused...

Comment: When I comment this line : `$("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('on');` it works partially. I mean when I switch off does not work as expected, however switching on is being prevented as expected. As I told before I need to find some solution to prevent running else statement in case of entering `if()` statement

Comment: Right, thats what I don't understand it seems like both conditions are happening, otherwise the if and else would remain separate, can you debug this in the browser dev tools and find out what is triggering the extra logic?

Set some break points just before this logic runs and step through it, that might get the exact place things are going wrong.

Comment: The next thing I could suggest is, try to break this down into a small chunk of functionality, don't do any ajax call, just get some function to run when the checkbox is checked and when it gets unchecked, if you can get that working you know it has something to do with the ajax call.

Comment: Well, I have already down that, and it does not relate to the ajax part, it relates to checkbox part.

Comment: oh I see what might be happening with your infinite loop

Comment: don't use on change event, I think that is where its going wrong, when the request completes, just set the property

if I understand the full functionality here, you want the check box checked when the request completes, not from a user checking it

But when the request completes it keeps firing the change event and calling the request again, does that seem right to you?

Comment: And how I am going to do that no idea :) Because in that case I have to delete onToggle function completely. Thinking about it...

Comment: I may not be seeing the full context here, can you add a screen shot of the UI, but I do think that when the request completes, it keeps firing the onChange event which keeps calling the request, look in the network tab do you see the same request going out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247715/discussion-between-orkhan-orkhan-and-wpw).